# Converting Request.QueryString to integer

Tags: c#, request.querystring

How do i convert a Request.Query string to an integer value. I've tried all the Convert.ToInt32 and Int32.Parse but it says Input string is not in the correct format. I am using the string value as an input to a stored procedure which takes in only integer types for that field.

Here's a part of the code-

```
string rid=Request.QueryString["RID"];
lblRID.Text = rid;
int id= Int32.Parse(rid);

    if (lblRID.Text!= null)
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_NewResource_get", myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RID",id);  //RID is int in database and stored procedure
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: suggest you post some code...

Comment: Is this C# or something else?

Please tag appropriately...

Answer (score 10):

```
int foo;
int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["foo"], out foo);
```

or just like you say, `int.Parse` should convert to int

Could you post some code here ?

Comment: string rid=Request.QueryString["RID"];
        lblRID.Text = rid;
        int id= Int32.Parse(rid);

I've tried that and

string rid=Request.QueryString["RID"];
        lblRID.Text = rid;
        int id= Convert.ToInt32(lblRID.Text) or int id= Convert.ToInt32(rid)

Comment: HeadScratcher. Could you update your original post putting the code in a codeblock so we can read it easier.
I think Barbaros is right with his TryParse, you might also want to look at string.IsNullOrEmpty to check the contents of the query string

Comment: i tried tryparse..Using TryParse executes d statements after the if statement correctly(button visibilty executes perfectly after the if) but im using RID(which is int) in the WHERE clause in a stored procedure to read fields from a table.. and using tryparse just does not convert querystring to int

Answer (score 7):

The answer thesedays varies based on what framework you're using as msft has made query params part of the view attribute model now for binding (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

You can still access most things via httpcontext for the sake of example.

`var fooIsInt = int.TryParse(HttpContext.Request.Query["foo"], out var foo);`

### Original Example for webforms in .net 2.0

Quick and dirty (and in a page load because this is an example, you should be able to work out what's happening from this)

```
<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
        
        string test = Request.QueryString["foo"];

        //Convert the query string you captured to an int and store it in an int.
        int intTest = Convert.ToInt32(test); 

        Response.Write(intTest.GetType() + "<br>" + intTest);   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about looking on the input that you provide to Int32.Parse?

Comment: Ok.. Im passing a request ID from a page in a gridview to another page and i've given the - string rid=Request.QueryString["RID"] on the page load.. Now i need to display this string in a label on the page and then convert it into an integer so that i can use it as an input to a stored procedure..

Comment: look in debugger what you have inside rid variable.

Comment: string rid=Request.QueryString["RID"];
        lblRID.Text = rid;
        int id= Int32.Parse(rid); ---->Shows input string not in a correct format error here
        if (lblRID.Text!= null)
        Statements after this if are executing normally

Comment: what is the VALUE of variable rid? What is displayed on the label?

Comment: the label displays integer values.. RID is an integer

Comment: CAN YOU POST THE VALUE HERE PLEASE?!?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

We use a base class from which every Page inherits. We have the following method that returns integer values from querystring params:

```
protected int FetchQueryStringIdentifierByKey(string key)
{
    int identifier;
    var isInt = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString[key], out identifier);
    return (isInt) ? identifier : 0;
}
```

[Credit](http://web.archive.org/web/20100527041622/http://jaysonknight.com/blog/articles/1756.aspx) goes to [Jayson Knight](http://twitter.com/jaysonknight) for his research into his original bench-marking results under .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
string id = Request.QueryString["RID"].ToString(); 
userid=Convert.ToInt32(id);
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about using TryParse like this:

```
string rid = Request.QueryString["RID"];
int id = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rid) && Int32.TryParse(rid, out id))
{
    lblRID.Text = rid;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_NewResource_get", myConnection);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RID",id);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Execute...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value passed in the query string with the RID parameter is not a number, so it cant be parsed to an int. E.g you have `?RID=hello` or maybe no RID parameter at all (in which case the value is null). Inspect the querystring to see the actual value passed.